# How to save primary key to another table as FK in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I am confused in this problem i have two model one is (business_master) and other one is ( page_master)

I want to save primary key (id) from business_master table to (page_master) as Fk (business_id).

Right now i hardcoded business_id in my controller.

My Controller:

```
        $page = new Page();
        $page->page_name = Input::get('page_name');
        $page->page_url = Input::get('page_url');
        $page->business_id = 1;

        $page->save();
```

and its model:

```
          class Page extends Model
        {
        protected $table = 'page_master';

     protected $fillable = ['business_id','page_url','page_name'];
    }
```

And my businees_master Model:

```
   class Business extends Model
  {
   protected $table = 'business_master';

protected $fillable = ['user_id','business_name','business_url'];


 }
```

how i can save business_id into my page_master table using relationships?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
                   public function addPage(Request $id)
{
    $fieldsValidation = [

        'page_name' => 'required|unique:page_master,page_name',
        'page_url' => 'required|unique:page_master,page_url',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $fieldsValidation);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $resultArray = [
            'status' => 0,
            'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
            'dataArray' => []

        ];
    } else {
        $business = Business::find(2);
        $page = new Page();
        $page->page_name = Input::get('page_name');
        $page->page_url = Input::get('page_url');
        $page->business()->associate($business);

        $page->save();
        $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Page url added!', 'dataArray' => $page];

    }
    return Response::json($resultArray, 200);


}
```

Comment: Send business id as parameter through routing

Comment: i can do that but its not suitable way i want to store this dynamically using relationships

Comment: can you show me with code?

Comment: what you mean by dynamically

Comment: Do you want the relationship like One **Business** hasMany **Page** ?

Comment: if i save my page_master table value the it should pick the business_id value automatically from business table and it can solve with relations ships but i dont idea how to do this

Comment: Yes i want to relationship one business has many page @Chirag

Comment: what are the conditions to pick business id? or pick randomly

Comment: pick randomly ...

Comment: $business=Business::where('your condition here')->first();  $business->id;

Comment: why you want to pick randomly without any conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two models

1) Business

2)Page

You have to define [one to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), 
So define relation **pages** in **Business** model

```
public function pages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Page');
}
```

And You have to define the Inverse relationship also in the **Page** model,

```
public function business()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Business');
}
```

After defining relationships, you can [query the relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

Like you are trying this query, So with the relationship you can do,

```
    $business = \Business::find(1); //here 1 as you gave but you can pass id as per your requirement
    $page = new Page();
    $page->page_name = Input::get('page_name');
    $page->page_url = Input::get('page_url');
    $page->business()->associate($business); 
    $page->save();
```

This will help you for sure. But you have to read the blog and understand the [Laravel relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#introduction)

Comment: it says Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::assosiate()

Comment: it gives an error because currently you don't have any business with id 1

Comment: i have business with id id 1 in my database

Comment: associate() function correct the spelling $page->business()->associate(Business::find(1));

Comment: @shahzad1122 I have updated my answer try this it's working or not?

Comment: one more question here we are passing static value business::find(1) but what here i want to pass the dyanamic value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168706/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-shahzad1122).